# Are these two self executing anonymous Javascript functions equivalent?

Tags: javascript

Is this:

```
(function(a) { 
    return 3;
})(this);
```

equivalent to:

```
(function() {
    return 3;
})();
```

If there are *any* differences, please explain

Comment: They're equal since you're doing nothing with that parameter.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Are parameters in Javascript optional?  Because unless they are, those two functions are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are, you can pass any number of parameters to a function, even if none are defined they can be accessed via the arguments array.  Any unpassed parameters are simply undefined.

Comment: The 2nd one doesn't have access to whatever `this` is, so *no* they are not.

Comment: I was just curious if passing the "this" variable made any difference

Comment: @user2202911 it doesnt make a difference in this case, but it you wanted to have access to whatever `this` is that is how you would do it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The only difference is the parameters and this is obivious. The OP is asking for something more, in the behaviour etc... or else it will be same like asking if *"a == b?"* ...

Comment: I am not sure exactly what "this" is supposed to be. I'll do more research and will come back with a better defined question if I have one

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: We can't really answer this without more context then.

Comment: @RocketHazmat sure, because of this I believe this question should be close as off-topic. This is a discussion, not a real question.

Comment: I saw this coding style used in an open source library, I will ask another - better defined question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the difference I think you're looking for: the second example has access to the outer `this` (through the `a` variable), while the second example does not.

Normally, you don't *need* to pass in arguments to an IIFE (although you certainly *can*, to get more readable or modular code), because newly-declared functions have access to their outer scope variables:

```
var foobar = 5;
(function() {
    // I can use the outer-scope `foobar` in here!
})();
```

However, `this` is an exceptional case, because the newly-created function will have its *own* `this` that will shadow the outer `this`:

```
// outer here, `this` is one thing
(function() {
    // in here, `this` might be something else
    // because each new functions invocation sets `this` within the function
})();
```

You can see shadowing behavior with non-`this` variables like this:

```
var foobar = 5;
(function() {
    var foobar = 7;
    // I can't use the outer-scope `foobar`
    // because it is shadowed by local-scope `foobar`
})();
```

A similar thing happens with `this`. In my `foobar` example, the shadowing was done explicitly, but with `this`, the shadowing always happens, because each function gets a new local-scope `this`.

You can access the outer `this` by aliasing it a new name, done here by formal argument:

```
// outer here, `this` is one thing
(function(outerThis) {
    // in here, `this` might be something else
    // but `outerThis` refers to the outer `this`
})(this);
```

If you don't alias the outer `this` to a new name, you will not have access to it, because it will be shadowed by local `this`. Note that you can also alias your outer `this` to another outer-scope variable, like:

```
var outerThis = this;
(function() {
    // we can access the outer-scope `outerThis` because it is not shadowed
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing the shadowing concept to me. I was unaware of it so I had difficulty verbalizing the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first you're passing an argument to, but it is never used. However, the functionality is the same for both. The second is slightly faster, due to not passing an argument for no reason, assuming this isn't just optimized away.

Comment: Do you have a benchmark to prove it's faster? Seems like it is likely to be dependent on the parser's optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define *equivalent*.

If you define it in terms of what the functions actually *do*, then, yes, they are equivalent. Although, of course, this is only true for their current content. One difference is that the first one has access to the outer `this`, while the second one doesn't - although this does not matter in your example.

Regarding to your comment whether just passing `this` makes a difference here: No, it does not.

If you define *equivalent* in a different way, then the functions *may* be different, e.g. when defining *equivalent* as having the same arity.

I guess the obvious counter-question would be what's the use case behind your question: *Why* do you ask this? (If it's not just out of curiosity and for academical reasons.)

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the "this" variable makes any difference behind the scenes.

Comment: I dont understand what the purpose of "this" is then, I saw a open source javascript library using this style and I'm trying to make sense of it. I will do some more research and come back with a better defined question.

Comment: @user2202911: Chances are, their function actually used the parameter passed to it, and didn't just `return 3;`.